# VBA: Range Variable in a SUMIF Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to use a range variable in a SUMIF function. The issue I have been running into with other answers I've seen is the variable being passed into the formula as 'N2':'N132' and resulting in a #NAME? error. I'm hoping to achieve not only the range being properly passed through but also having it locked $N$2:$N$132. the code is as follows:

Thank you for your help in advance.

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim x As range
Dim y As range



Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Open Orders 180-365")
sh1.Activate

Set x = range("N2", range("N2").End(xlDown))


range("K:K").Find(What:="Open Order Detail 90-179 Days", MatchCase:=True).Select

Selection.Offset(1, 3).Select

Set y = range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

range("D3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(R3C13:R132C13,RC[-2]," & x.Address(False, False) & ")"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `x.Address(False, False)`

Returns the address in A1 style and you cannot mix A1 and R1C1 styles:

```
range("D3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(R3C13:R132C13,RC[-2]," & x.Address(False, False,xlR1C1) & ")"
```

Comment: Thank you for the information! Looks like next on my list of VBA things to understand is the difference between A1 and R1C1.